# ¿Cómo puedo redirigir de .html a /?

Tags: .htaccess

Mi archivo .htaccess hace que las urls que acaban en .html se eliminen, sin embargo, el resultado no se observa, y da un error para encontrarlo, y el CSS y JS lo mismo. ¿Cómo puedo añadir además siempre una barra / al final de la dirección?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

Comment: "da un error" no es la mejor descripción del error que está ocurriendo. ¿Cuál es exactamente ese error? Si tiene un mensaje de error asociado, considero que debieras incluirlo como parte de la pregunta también.

Answer (score 0):

Tanto el titulo de la pregunta como su contenido podrían interpretarse de manera diferente. Prueba con esto a ver si te sirve:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L,R=301]
```